# Error downloading file in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, file, url, download, vba

I have this URL: 'https://www.oslobors.no/ob/servlets/excel?type=history&columns=DATE%2C+CLOSE%2C+BID%2C+ASK%2C+YIELD%2C+BID_YIELD%2C+ASK_YIELD%2C+VOLUME_TOTAL%2C+VWAP&format[DATE]=ddd.mm.YY&format[CLOSE]=%23%2C%23%230.00%23%23%23&format[BID]=%23%2C%23%230.00%23%23%23&format[ASK]=%23%2C%23%230.00%23%23%23&[YIELD]=%23%2C%23%230.00%23%23%23&format[BID_YIELD]=%23%2C%23%230.00%23%23&format[ASK_YIELD]=%23%2C%23%230.00%23%23&format[VOLUME_TOTAL]=%23%2C%23%230&format[VWAP]=%23%2C%23%230.00%23%23%23&header[DATE]=AASB05%20PRO&header[CLOSE]=Siste&header[BID]=Kj%C3%B8per&header[ASK]=Selger&header[YIELD]=Eff.%20rente%20siste&header[BID_YIELD]=Eff.%20rente%20kj%C3%B8p&header[ASK_YIELD]=Eff.%20rente%20salg&header[VOLUME_TOTAL]=Volum&header[VWAP]=VWAP&view=DELAYED&source=feed.abm.quotes.INSTRUMENTS&filter=ITEM_SECTOR%3D%3DsAASB05%20PRO.ABM%26%26DELETED!%3Dn1&stop=now&start=1448924400000&space=DAY&ascending=true&filename=data.xlsx'

And when trying:

```
Workbooks.Open(TheURL)
```

I get 'Run-time error '1004':'([error](http://oi67.tinypic.com/i4l54m.jpg)).

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution Explanation:***

Your URL is too big to be handled.

***Solution:*** 

Short it, there are many tools to do so, the best is to use Google URL Shortener 

I went ahead and did this for you, try the following URL 'https://goo(dot)gl/UoVGBg' instead (substitute the (dot) for the actual "." one).

Comment: Based on your answer(shorten URL) I found this: [link](http://scripting.com/stories/2007/06/27/tinyurlHasAnApi.html), Thank you!